# Can a couple still get married after committing sin together?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, sex

You both like each other and want to marry.  You have done sin astagfirullah, but you want to change your ways and make it halal and still get married.  Is it permissible, and how do you fix such sin?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what sin they did? is it having sex, or something else? Anyways I remember it's possible, so no despair. But there are details.

Answer (score 3):

Well i guess the answer -as far as i understand your question- is clear you can only try to get married!

This would mean the girl/woman should convince her parents the boy/man should propose for marriage by asking her parents!

But **before** this both should do repentance and expiation and real regretting and turn the sins into good deeds like praying, fasting,..., doing good things, helping: Being a good muslim and not redo those sins!

So you both should ask Allah for forgiveness and be better muslims.

And an other thing: About kissing a foreign woman i found this Hadith:

> Ibn Mas'ud (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: A man kissed a
>   woman. So he came to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and informed him about
>   it. Then Allah revealed this Ayah: "And perform the Salat, between the
>   two ends of the day and in some hours of the night. Verily, the good
>   deeds efface the evil deeds (i.e., minor sins)." ([11:114](http://legacy.quran.com/11/114)) The man
>   asked the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) whether this applies to him only. The
>   Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "It applies to all of my Ummah."
>
> [Sahih [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/9/5) & [Muslim]](http://sunnah.com/muslim/50/47)

and this [Fatwa](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=23208) in Arabic.

**More references**

And Allah knows best!

See also (In Arabic):

Fatwa from [islamweb](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=165167)

An [article](http://www.alukah.net/fatawa_counsels/0/30566/) on how to end up a haram relationship

Useful Fatwas in English:

All from islamqa [1](http://islamqa.info/en/183356), [2](http://islamqa.info/en/106288) & [3](http://islamqa.info/en/148528)

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score -1):

Whatever is the mistake we did in past, we cannot correct them but we can repent for them, so

1. Accept your mistake before Allah and
2. Promise not to do such kind of mistake in future and
3. Ask forgiveness for both of you.

He is most forgiving and merciful.

Comment: Altough the core of your answer is correct, the first statement seems to imply something else. Please rephrase it. Jazakallah Khair.